# Update row with minimum value sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
-----------------------
summonerId | timestamp
-----------------------
253222     | 14395235091096
929112     | 14395235091056
(...)
```

I want to update the row with the lower timestamp but I can't, when I do this

```
UPDATE summoners_shell 
SET 
summonerId = ".$s.",
timestamp = ".$time." 
WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MIN(timestamp))
```

It updates all rows! Why? How do I do what I want?

Comment: Are you sure the Query is Complete??

Comment: Select min timestamp from table.  Your code is timestamp = timestamp

Comment: `SELECT MIN(timestamp)`? From where exactly?

Comment: from summoners_shell, but it gives me an error if I put it there:  You can't specify target table 'summoners_shell' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Well this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html says "Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.". Is there as workaround then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When `SELECT`-subquery is in `WHERE`-clause, it locks the table so an update can not pass.
Just use `JOIN` instead

```
UPDATE summoners_shell AS s1
JOIN (SELECT MIN(timestamp) AS mt FROM summoners_shell) AS mt ON (s1.timestamp = mt.mt)
SET 
    summonerId = ".$s.",
    timestamp = ".$time."
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is not a typo then probably this query will serve your problem.

```
UPDATE summoners_shell 
    SET summonerId=".$s.",
    timestamp=".$time." 
WHERE timestamp=(
    SELECT MIN(timestamp)
    FROM 
    summoners_shell 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE summoners_shell SET summonerId=".$s.",timestamp=".$time." WHERE timestamp=(SELECT MIN(timestamp) FROM summoners_shell)
```

in subquery add this:

```
FROM summoners_shell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
UPDATE summoners_shell SET summonerId=".$s.",timestamp=".$time."
     WHERE timestamp=(SELECT MIN(timestamp) from summoners_shell)
```

Comment: I already tried it. It gives me this error:  You can't specify target table 'summoners_shell' for update in FROM clause