# Python MySql Update on same table

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
sql = 'UPDATE table1 SET address="City1" where id = MIN(id);'

cursor.execute(sql)

my_db.commit()
```

What I am trying to do is update the address for the lowest value of the PK (which should be 1 but I plan to add another condition and I want to make sure this works first). I am new to Python and I am using PyCharm 2018 for Windows 32.
I searched for the answer but with no luck. I hope you can help. If this is a duplicate I am sorry to waste your time, but any answer is appreciated. Thanks people!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update row with minimum value sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001933/update-row-with-minimum-value-sql)

Answer (score -1):

```
sql = "UPDATE projects, " \
      "(SELECT min(id) AS number FROM projects) AS rez " \
      "SET address = 'City' " \
      "WHERE projects.id = rez.number;"

cursor.execute(sql)

my_db.commit()
```

Comment: what is wrong with this code? please explain.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

I found this down at the bottom:

Another possibility is to rewrite the subquery so that it does not use IN or EXISTS, like this:


UPDATE items,
       (SELECT id, retail / wholesale AS markup, quantity FROM items)
       AS discounted
    SET items.retail = items.retail * 0.9
    WHERE discounted.markup >= 1.3
    AND discounted.quantity < 100
    AND items.id = discounted.id;


In this case, the subquery is materialized by default rather than merged, so it is not necessary to disable merging of the derived table.